Why is MaterialAutoCompleteTextView rendered differently than TextInputEditText?
I have a TextInputEditText and a MaterialAutoCompleteTextView inside a TextInputLayout:
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/name">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/category">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Apart from the different tag, they are identical. However, this is what it looks like:

The font in the MaterialAutoCompleteTextView is larger and there is no padding.

Is there an obvious reason why this is rendered differently?

Is there an easy way to make it look like the TextInputEditText (thus, without fiddling)?



You can customize MaterialAutoCompleteTextView so that it looks similar to TextInputEditText.
MaterialAutoCompleteTextView extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView extends EditText
Please check the source code from here.
So all properties and customisations of EditText is applicable on MaterialAutoCompleteTextView .
Following that customising the style by override font size and padding properties to match TextInputEditText.
Check the below steps :
1. styles.xml:
<style name="CustomAutoCompleteTextViewStyle"
    parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_normal</item>  <item name="android:padding">@dimen/default_padding_small</item>  </style>

2. dimen.xml:
Defined for that resource in your dimen.xml file.
<dimen name="default_padding_small">8dp</dimen>

3. Updated MaterialAutoCompleteTextView :
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/category">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/CustomAutoCompleteTextViewStyle" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Update 1:
Why MaterialAutoCompleteTextView renders differently than TextInputEditText?

Inheritance:
MaterialAutoCompleteTextView is a class that overrides AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView which, in turn, extends the EditText however, MaterialAutoCompleteTextView applies its styling on top of the EditText. This styling fulfills the Material Design look and differs from the default EditText look.

Font Size and Padding:
The MaterialAutoCompleteTextView contains larger default size font and less padding relative to the TextInputEditText. They can even have a visually different look that results from the interaction process.

Customization:
MaterialComponents which contains MaterialAutoCompleteTextView have its own styles by default. Some of these styles can be applied by overriding the default styles for EditText.



I did give your answer an upvote because I think it useful, but I did not accept it because it basically suggests what I consider fiddling. The problem is that, should Google mess with TextInputEditText, I would have to fiddle again with MaterialAutoCompleteTextView to make them look alike.

@user1785730 Thanks for the upvote MaterialAutoCompleteTextView and TextInputEditText render differently primarily due to their distinct purposes and implementations within the Material Design library. Also the way I suggested is considered as "customisation as per requirement" rather than saying as fiddling. Anyways I have upvoted you already on 5th June since I consider your question interesting.

Suggestion: if you don't want the look of MaterialAutoCompleteTextView then you may consider TextInputEditText with adapter and addTextChangedListener after that in onTextChanged use showDropDown. I can post it as the update in the answer if you say so. Please check https://m3.material.io/components/search/overview and https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/overview.

@user1785730 please check my update 1 section of the answer.
